# Let $X(t)=(1-t)\int_{0}^{t}\frac{dB(s)}{1-s}$ I want find $dX(t)$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Let $X(t)=(1-t)\int_{0}^{t}\frac{dB(s)}{1-s}$, where $0\le t < 1$.Find $dX(t)$.

thanks  for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Y(t) = \int_0^t \frac{dB(s)}{1-s}$ so that $X(t) = (1-t) Y(t)$. You can now use Ito formula to get
$$dX(t) = -Y(t) dt + (1-t) dY(t) = -Y(t) dt + (1-t) \frac{dB(t)}{1-t} = -\frac{X(t)}{1-t} dt + dB(t)$$
that is the required differential equation for $X(t)$. Notice that $X(t)$ is the Brownian bridge with initial point $a=0$ and final point $b=0$ in the time interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: are you can solve this question i am try to solve that for this person but i cant I think he nedd the answer.               []:=http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80995/i-want-to-show-mt-e-fract2-sinbt-is-a-martingale-by-using-ito-s-f

Answer (score 0):

HINT : $dB(s) = B'(s)ds$ so let $$f(s) = \frac{B'(s)}{1-s}$$ Therefore you can write the integral as :$$\int^t_0f(s)ds = F(t) - F(0)$$

Differentiate to find $dX(t)$.

Note that using my notation, $dF(t) = f(t)dt$.

Comment: this question about stochastic not calculus.